# How to have AWS RDS synchronous read replication?

Tags: database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

For AWS RDS there are 2 way to create a "clone" of your DB :

1/ Read replica : Create a read replica, data is asynchronous, meaning there's a little delay

2/ Multi-AZ standby : Create a standby DB, data is synchronous, meaning it's exactly same all the time; but this is for fail-over and cannot be used unless main DB down.

So the "synchronous" ability is there already, but I don't find any option to have a synchronous read only replica.

For my case, I want to have read replica to reduce read load on main DB, but data is very sensitive so cannot afford to read old data at all, any suggestion for my case here with AWS RDS service ? like making the "standby" being readable.

Comment: Were you able to do some research about how much is the replication delay in read replica? How fast is your application making request for the latest data after it updates it? Did you consider using caching?

Comment: Hi, my question is more for learning purpose than actual practical, I just consider for extreme case when I want my read DB to have little to no delayed, how can I do it with AWS, and other related topic doesn't satisfy me. And also, caching is another topic, I want to focus on DB only perspective.

Comment: Synchronous replication is not supported by AWS RDS service natively also there is no custom solution available which allows to override the way AWS RDS is doing the replication. I suggest caching because you can update the cache right after writing data to the writer endpoint of the database so that the immediate get operation can get the latest data from cache without hitting db reader endpoint while replication is being performed. If this issue of replication lag can be solved it will be a big win.

Answer (score 4):

There is a new option in RDS that allows having two readable standbys with synchronous replication: https://aws.amazon.com/rds/features/multi-az/#Amazon_RDS_Multi-AZ_with_two_readable_standbys. It's a relatively new offering that still needs testing if there is really no lag when you read from replicas.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Postgres or MySQL, you can deploy to [Aurora](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/AuroraUserGuide/CHAP_AuroraOverview.html) rather than standard RDS. It uses a shared data storage layer, so gives you synchronous read replicas, in addition to improved data durability and automatic failover.